# What major fiscal policy actions were taken during the Great Recession (2007-09)?

Tags: macroeconomics, fiscal-policy, government, keynesian-economics

What major fiscal policy actions were taken during the Great Recession (2007-2009)?

Comment: Bush passed the Economic Stimulus Act of 2008 and also the Emergency Economic Stabilization Act of 2008 which established the Troubled Assets Relief Program. Obama passed the American Recovery and Reinvestment Act in early 2009. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The rest of the world?

Comment: Is this question focused on the US?